# Find the unit vector $\vec{b}$ if $-\hat{i}+\hat{j}-\hat{k}$ bisects the angle between $\vec{b}$ and $\vec a=3\hat{i}+4\hat{j}$

Tags: vectors

> Find the unit vector $\vec{b}$ if $-\hat{i}+\hat{j}-\hat{k}$ bisects the angle between $\vec{b}$ and $\vec a=3\hat{i}+4\hat{j}$

The unit vector along the angle bisector is

$$\frac{-\hat{i}+\hat{j}-\hat{k}}{\sqrt3}=\frac{\vec{b}+\left(\frac35\hat{i}+\frac45\hat{j}\right)}{|\vec{b}+\frac35\hat{i}+\frac45\hat{j}|}$$

Im not able to extract $\vec b$ from here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the vector formula for the bisector of given two vectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2285965/how-to-find-the-vector-formula-for-the-bisector-of-given-two-vectors) Just apply the formula given

Comment: I think OP is right - the proposed answer is not a unit vector.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore how is this a duplicate? The problem that OP has is very different. Here the bisector is given and the vector needs to be obtained. OP has already written the equation. The challenge is in separating unit vector from the equation which requires a different working.

Comment: @MathLover exactly! I wondered why this happened. Nevertheless I received great answers, so I let it go.

Comment: @DatBoi a duplicate question may even get deleted at some point. will wait to hear from Albus if it was just an oversight.

Comment: @MathLover sure. Ill flag for mods after albus' reply

Comment: @MathLover I overlooked it  my apologies to you and OP ,voted to reopen

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore It's completely alright! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that if $ \ \vec b \ $ is a unit vector and $- \hat i + \hat j - \hat k$ is angle bisector of $\vec b$ and $\vec a \ (= 3 \hat i + 4 \hat j)$, we have

$ \displaystyle \frac{-\hat{i}+\hat{j}-\hat{k}}{\sqrt3}=\frac{\vec{b}+\left(\frac35\hat{i}+\frac45\hat{j}\right)}{|\vec{b}+\frac35\hat{i}+\frac45\hat{j}|}$

Let's say $ \displaystyle |\vec{b}+\frac35\hat{i}+\frac45\hat{j}| = m$ where $m$ is magnitude.

Then, $ \displaystyle \vec b = \ \left(-\dfrac{m}{\sqrt3} - \dfrac{3}{5}\right)\hat i +  \left(\dfrac{m}{\sqrt3} - \dfrac{4}{5}\right)\hat j -\dfrac{m}{\sqrt3} \hat k \ $ ....$(i)$

and $ \left(-\dfrac{m}{\sqrt3} - \dfrac{3}{5}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{m}{\sqrt3} - \dfrac{4}{5}\right)^2 + \dfrac{m^2}{3} = 1$

Simplifying, $m^2 - \dfrac{2m}{5\sqrt3} = 0$

and we get $m = \dfrac{2}{5\sqrt3}$

Substituting $m$ in $(i)$, $ \ \vec b = - \dfrac{1}{15} (11 \hat i + 10 \hat j + 2 \hat k)$

Comment: Truly incredible!

Comment: @DatBoi thank you for your kind words.

Comment: I really liked the way you assumed that modulus to be a scalar and found its value! Are there any other applications of this?

Comment: I know I have used it in the past to make work easier. Don't recollect the scenarios though.

Answer (score 2):

Because a rhombus’s diagonals bisect its interior angles, in general, a bisector of the angle between vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ is $$\hat{\mathbf u}+\hat{\mathbf v}.$$

Therefore, for our problem: there exists some positive $k$ for which $$\mathbf b+\frac1{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}\begin{pmatrix} 3 \cr 4 \cr 0 \end{pmatrix}=k\begin{pmatrix} -1 \cr 1 \cr -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Since $\mathbf b$ is a unit vector, it must be that$$\left(-k-\frac35\right)^2+\left(k-\frac45\right)^2+\left(-k\right)^2=1\\k=-\frac2{15}.$$ ($k$ being negative means that, contrary to the problem statement, the given vector is actually an *exterior* bisector of the angle between $\mathbf b$ and $\mathbf a.$)

Thus, $$\mathbf b=-\frac1{15}\begin{pmatrix} 11 \cr 10 \cr 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

### Correction

$k$ actually equals positive $\frac2{15}$ (the preceding lines and final answer remain correct), so the given vector *is* indeed the specified bisector.

Comment: @MathLover 1. Thanks for the catch! Am leaving the original answer in case the parenthetical bit has instructional value.  2. Nope, I disagree but that this question duplicates the cited one; I shall vote to reopen.