# Find the unit vector

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry

> Let the given vectors be: $\vec a= \vec u+ \vec v$ , $\vec b = 2\vec u + \vec v$ , $|\vec u| = 2$ $,|\vec v| = 4$ and angle between vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ is $120^\circ$.
> Express the unit vector $\vec x$ over vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ if $\vec x$ bisects the angle between vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.

I dont know how to find this unit vector. I know that $\cos(\angle(a,b)) = \dfrac{\vec a\vec b}{|\vec a||\vec b|}$. But I don't know what to do with it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hint: compute $|\vec a|,|\vec b|,\vec y=\frac{\vec a}{|\vec a|}+\frac{\vec b}{|\vec b|},$ and $\vec x=\frac{\vec y}{|\vec y|}.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Why are you answering the question in a comment?

Comment: @Arthur Because it is just a hint. I remember having been recently strongly criticized by a well-known moderator for editing such an "incomplete" (but easy to complete) answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank You very much, I calculated it. But can You please explain to me why is vector y equal to that, and why is vector x equal to that

Comment: Draw two arbitrary *unit* vectors $a',b'.$ Then, the two vectors $a'\pm b'$ bissect the two angles between them, don't they? The rest of the hint was just to divide (three times) vectors by their norm to make unit vectors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the vector formula for the bisector of given two vectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2285965/how-to-find-the-vector-formula-for-the-bisector-of-given-two-vectors)

Comment: Yes, Thank You very much. I am learning for my exam and I want to really understand it not just to know the answer. You really helped me I am very greatful @AnneBauval